# Meaning of the name Moki

Tags: meaning, names

Can someone please tell me what the name Moki means in English? And is it a boy's or girl's name?

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure that it's a Japanese name? Moreover, a given name?

Answer (score 3):

(Translation requests are generally not allowed on this site, so this issue might be closed by site moderators.)

There's a fellow named Jim Breen who maintains a few online dictionaries, including a name dictionary.  [Looking up "Moki" on his site](http://nihongo.monash.edu/cgi-bin/wwwjdic?2MUJMoki), we find that this is an unusual name -- only three instances pop up.

- 茂木【もき】 (s) Moki
- 茂幾【もき】 (s) Moki
- 毛木【もき】 (u) Moki

Here, the `(s)` indicates a surname, and the `(u)` indicates an as-yet-unclassified name.  (Code legend available [here](http://nihongo.monash.edu/wwwjdicinf.html#code_tag).)  I'll guess here that the last bullet point is also a surname.

In terms of what "Moki" means, I must caution that Japanese names are sometimes not very directly connected to meaning, much like names in English or other languages.  If we just go from the meanings inherent in the kanji spellings, we have:

- 茂木【もき】: "lush" + "tree"
- 茂幾【もき】: "lush" + "how many"
- 毛木【もき】: "hair, hairy" + "tree"

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you! It's a name for my cat so Hairy Tree is quite fitting :)